# SOLR: Search spellcheck cases handling is not proper

Tags: solr

> **Case 1:**

If I search for "`Name:blck`", the result is as below -- **which is correct**

No result found and spellcheck suggestion for "black"

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":119,
    "params":{
      "q":"Name:blck",
      "fl":"Name",
      "rows":"5",
      "_":"1582184918494"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  },
  "spellcheck":{
    "suggestions":[
      "blck",{
        "numFound":1,
        "startOffset":5,
        "endOffset":9,
        "origFreq":0,
        "suggestion":[{
            "word":"black",
            "freq":32435}]}],
    "correctlySpelled":false}}
```

> **Case 2**

If I search for "`Name:blck+top`", the result is as below -- **here I need spellcheck for blck word**

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":48,
    "params":{
      "q":"Name:blck+top",
      "fl":"Name",
      "rows":"5",
      "_":"1582184918494"}},
  "response":{"numFound":14442,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "Name":"Shimmery Seamless Top"},
      {
        "Name":"Ruffle Sleeve Top"},
      {
        "Name":"Ruffle Sleeve Top"},
      {
        "Name":"Ruffle Sleeve Top"},
      {
        "Name":"Ruffle Sleeve Top"}]
  },
  "spellcheck":{
    "suggestions":[],
    "correctlySpelled":true}}
```

So, Basically I just want to show the spellcheck suggestion if any word from the search is wrong.

Comment: whats the fieldtype applied for your field?

Comment: field type for Name is text_general

Comment: I have added the the spell check configuration as well for you to compare with yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the result for my field which has below data in solr.

```
{
    "description":"Black Top"
},
{
    "description":"Sleeve Top"
},
{
    "description":"Seamless Top"
}
```

My field is `description` and the its defined in the `solr.xml` as below.

```
<field name="description" type="text_general"/>
```

The query for the same is :

```
http://10.168.72.101:8983/solr/knowledge_combined/select?df=description&fl=description&q=blck%20top&spellcheck=on
```

Here is the response I Received from solr.

[image: Solr Spell check Response]

Here is the spell check configuration added in the `solr.config.xml`

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">

    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>

    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">default</str>
      <str name="field">description</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
      <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
      <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
      <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
      <int name="minPrefix">1</int>
      <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
      <int name="minQueryLength">4</int>
      <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.01</float>
    </lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
      <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">5</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

Comment: Yes... it works for me as well.. there was small mistake in my solrconfig.xml